# javascript .closest to utilise either one of two selectors

Tags: javascript

I'm currently utilizing .closest in vanilla js to find a div(modal container) with a certain class, then on click of the button closes that div(modal container). all works fine,  but the issue i'm running into now is I need to find either one of two divs(two different types of modals). So depending which one of these "div (modal containers)" are  closest to the  button - close that modal.

```
<div class="modal-a">
 <div class="modal__header">
   <button class="btn" data-close-btn>close</button>
 </div>
  
</div>

<div class="modal-b">
  <button class="btn" data-close-btn>close</button>
</div>
```

//-------------- Javacript

```
const closeBtn = querySelectorAll(['data-close-btn]);

closeBtn.forEach(button => {
  const modal = button.closest('.modal-a'); // works as expected
  button.addEventListener('click', (e)=> closeModal(modal));
});


function closeModal(modal) {
  modal.classList.remove('.active');
}
```

what im trying to achieve

```
const modal = button.closest('.modal-a') || button.closest('.modal-b');
const modal = button.closest('.modal-a, .modal-b');
```

both these obviously fails the first time but works thereafter although in the console there is always a failure on click, so how do i write this to only use the relevant selector?

Hope this makes sense what im trying to explain.

Comment: what is your html ?

Comment: nothing needed from html. this is a js query. As I stated it work 100% fin in the first part where I only have one selector. ;)

Comment: your button and your modal are HTML elements, can you show them?

Comment: added simple version of html

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single eventlistener and event delegation for that:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", e => {
  target = e.target.closest(".modal-a, .modal-b")

  if(!target || !e.target.matches("[data-close-btn]")) return;
  
  alert("You clicked a modal-Button")
})
```

```html
<div class="modal-a">
  <button class="btn" data-close-btn>close</button>
</div>

<div class="modal-b">
  <button class="btn" data-close-btn>close</button>
</div>

<h2>Button outside of any Modal</h2>
<button class="btn" data-close-btn>close</button>
```